# moving element from light DOM to ShadowDOM without disconnectedCallback

Tags: javascript, web-component, shadow-dom, custom-element, native-web-component

I wonder if I am on the right track here

**Objective:** Need to ensure that all elements end up in the shadowDOM

So the **manually** created HTML file

```
<cardts-pile>
  <cardts-card>A</cardts-card>
  <cardts-card>B</cardts-card>
</cardts-pile>
```

creates the cards in **light**DOM of `<cardts-pile>`

if I then move them to shadowDOM (ofcourse):

► `<cardts-card>` is removed from the DOM (triggering `disconnectedCallback()`)
► `<cardts-card>` is added again (triggering `connectedCallback()`)

[see console.log on Run Code Snipper below]

I have more fancy code in `card.connectedCallback()`
on 're-connect' it is basically triggering the exact **same** code **again**.

### Questions

1. Is it possible to move nodes without DOM changes?
2. Is there OOTB code to check if an **existing** `<cardts-card>` is only being moved,
   so `connectedCallback` knows it doesn't need to run code again.
3. Should I be doing something different,
   making those lightDOM elements end up in shadowDOM immediatly?

```js
customElements.define('cardts-pile', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'}).innerHTML='<slot></slot>';
  }
  connectedCallback() {
    console.log('connect pile');
  }
});

customElements.define('cardts-card', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'}).innerHTML='<slot></slot>';
  }
  connectedCallback() {
    console.log('connect card',this.innerText);
    if (!this.getRootNode().host) // not in shadowDOM
       this.parentNode.shadowRoot.insertBefore(this,null);//or appendChild
  }
  disconnectedCallback() {
    console.log('disconnect card',this.innerText);
  }
});
```

```html
<cardts-pile>
  <cardts-card>A</cardts-card>
  <cardts-card>B</cardts-card>
</cardts-pile>
```

Comment: why don't you use instead slotchange event instead?

Comment: [blush] Because I didn't know about ``slotchange``.... On reading the [slotchange docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/slotchange) It seems to me it is more like a MutationObserver on a slot, doesn't look like it will prevent ``disconnectedCallback()``

Comment: you're right... i didn't understand the goal of your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to move nodes without DOM changes?

No (as far as I know about Shadow DOM).

> Is there OOTB code to check if an existing  is only being moved?

I would use a boolean flag:

```
connectedCallback() {
    if ( !this.connected )
        console.log( 'creation' )
    else {
        console.log( 'move' )
    this.connected = true   
}
```

(or in `disconnectedCallack`)

```js
customElements.define('cardts-pile', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'}).innerHTML='<slot></slot>';
        this.shadowRoot.addEventListener( 'slotchange', ev => {      
            let node = this.querySelector( 'cardts-card' )
            node && this.shadowRoot.append( node )
        })
    }
    connectedCallback() {
        console.log('connect pile');
    }
});
    
customElements.define('cardts-card', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'}).innerHTML='<slot></slot>';
    }
    connectedCallback() {
        if ( !this.connected )
            console.log( this.innerText + ' created' )
        else 
            console.log( this.innerText + ' moved' )
        this.connected = true 
    }
    disconnectedCallback() {
        if ( !this.moved )
            console.log( 'moving ' + this.innerText );
        else 
            console.log( 'really disconnected' )
        this.moved = true
    }
});
```

```html
<cardts-pile>
  <cardts-card>A</cardts-card>
  <cardts-card>B</cardts-card>
</cardts-pile>
```

> Should I be doing something different?

You could instead define or upgrade `<cardts-card>` only after the *unknown* elements are moved, if possible though I don't think it's a good practice unless you can control the whole execution timing, for example with `whenDefined()` or with ordered HTML and Javascript code:

```
customElements.define('cardts-pile', Pile)
customElements.whenDefined('cardts-pile').then(() => 
    customElements.define('cardts-card', Card)
)
```

In the example below, you define class `Pile` before or after class `Card` (depending on how they are related).

```js
class Card extends HTMLElement {
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'}).innerHTML='<slot></slot>'
    }
    connectedCallback() {
        console.log(this.innerText + ' connected')
    }
    disconnectedCallback() {
         console.log(this.innerText + ' disconnected')
    }
}

class Pile extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'})
    }
    connectedCallback() {
        console.log('connect pile')
        this.shadowRoot.append(...this.querySelectorAll('cardts-card'))
    }
}

window.onload = () => customElements.define('cardts-pile', Pile)
customElements.whenDefined('cardts-pile').then(() => 
    customElements.define('cardts-card', Card)
)
```

```html
<cardts-pile>
  <cardts-card>A</cardts-card>
  <cardts-card>B</cardts-card>
</cardts-pile>
```

Comment: ► 1. You are my hero on Elements/shadowDOM, so the answer is NO. ► 2. No need for an extra flag, ``!this.getRootNode().host`` IS the flag ► 3. On first sight (indeed not good practive as you said) I can't use your example code, as ``<cardts-pile>`` now has a dependency on (needs to know about) ``<cardts-card>`` (there is other stuff going into pile as well). I am going to continue with ►2◄  (leaving the question open for other answers for now)

Comment: :-) actually this.getRootNode.host could return true if your component is contained itself in a Shadow DOM container (it depends if you control the global layout of the page or if intend to redistribute you webapp). Nota: it's not clear but my example code was illustrating #2, not #3.